# Image not replacing with variation image

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to create a function which replaces the head image with the variation image clicked. I did make a function but I am getting an error in the console. Here is the function:

```
// add this to functions.php
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product','custom_woocommerce_additional_variation_images');

function custom_woocommerce_additional_variation_images(){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   (function($) {
        $(window).load(function(){
            $( "a.swatch-anchor").click(function() {
                //console.log(variation);
                var atts = $(this).parent().attr('data-value');
                var product_variations = $('form.variations_form').data('product_variations');
                console.log(product_variations);        
                var variation_id = '';
                    for ( var i = 0; i < product_variations.length; i++ ) {
                        var variation = product_variations[i];
                            if( product_variations[i].attributes.attribute_pa_kleur == atts){
                                    variation_id = product_variations[i].variation_id;
                            }
                    }

                console.log(variation_id);

                var data = {
                    security: wc_additional_variation_images_local.ajaxImageSwapNonce,
                    variation_id: variation_id,
                    post_id: $( 'form.variations_form' ).data( 'product_id' )
                };
                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: $.wc_additional_variation_images_frontend.getAjaxURL( 'get_images' ),
                  data: data,
                  cache: false,
                  success: function(data,response){                  
                      data = $.parseJSON(data);
                      console.log(data['main_images']);
                      $('.woocommerce-product-gallery').replaceWith(data['main_images']);

                  },

                });

            });
        })

    })(jQuery);
</script>
<?php 
}

add_filter( 'wc_additional_variation_images_custom_swap', '__return_true');
add_filter( 'wc_additional_variation_images_custom_reset_swap', '__return_true' );
add_filter( 'wc_additional_variation_images_custom_original_swap', '__return_true' );
add_filter( 'wc_additional_variation_images_get_first_image', '__return_true' );
```

The console is returning: `Uncaught ReferenceError: wc_additional_variation_images_local is not defined`

Here is the website which I am using: https://www.dev.ruitershopboxmeer.nl/product/kingsland-zadeldekje-carin/

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not a PHP developer, but you might consider re-structuring your code, to have more named functions and less large code blocks. This is also good practice for "Clean Code". With more context with named functions, you may find people more willing to help. Otherwise this is a lot of syntax to parse without a lot of context.

Comment: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FunctionLength.html